# Compiler giving an "error: cannot find symbol" message. I think it has to do with the methods

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, method-call

I'm trying to have the main method call the newGame method but it's giving me an error.

error: cannot find symbol
newGame(answer);
symbol: variable answer
location: class GuessingGame

```
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame {
   
public static newGame(int answer){
 
 Random rand = new Random(int answer);
 answer = rand.nextInt(51); 
 }     

public static void main (String [] args ){
   newGame(answer);   
 }
}
```

Comment: You need a return type before ```newGame(int answer)```

Comment: You haven't defined the `answer` variable in `main()`, either.

Comment: A return in the class instead of the method?? That doesn't make sense though.

Comment: `public static newGame` - There is something missing after `static` and before `newGame`.

Comment: The `new Random(int answer)` is incorrect.  The `int` keyword should not be there.  You are not *declaring* a new `answer` variable.  You are (apparently) using an `answer` variable that already exists.  Except ... that `new Random(someNumber)` actually means "create a random number generator with `someNumber` as the seed.  You probably *don't* mean that.  So `new Random()` is probebly the correct thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted code is missing a few things, and doesn't do much. I assume you want to return the new random value from `newGame` (and thus it should `return` an `int`). Also, it's better to pass the `Random` to your method (because creating a new `Random` involves seeding it, and if you do it quickly in a loop you can pick the same seed). So, that might look like

```
public static int newGame(Random rand) {
    return rand.nextInt(51);
}
```

Then you need to save the `answer` in `main`. And construct the `Random`. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int answer = newGame(rand);
}
```

Comment: It's just the start of a project and I was squeezing a stress ball because I couldn't figure it out. Thank you so much.